# seeking a solution for when user decrements a cell's value, another cell (different column) will increment that same value

Tags: vba, excel

example:

```
Column A = 1
Column B = 0
```

[user changes value of `Column A` to `0`]

new values:

```
Column A = 0
Column B = 1
```

Comment: Can they change the value of B also, or just A?

Comment: I take it you can't put a formula in column B - something like `= 1 - Column A` ?

Comment: ideally, the two related columns can change values both ways

Comment: Can you have hidden column where you  store sum of `columns A` and `B` as values?  These values would need to get updated on `workbook_open`

Comment: Your main issue is that when a cell changes, you lose it's previous value. I'd suggest researching Events and there are plenty of examples of ways to overcome that. Once you have some code, if you're still struggling to get it to work then we should be better placed to help further. (or.. if you're *really* lucky, you might get someone generous enough to do it for you..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for columns **A** and **B**.  Insert this event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, OldValue As Variant, NewValue As Variant, Delta As Variant
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        NewValue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        OldValue = Target.Value     'capture previous value
        Target.Value = NewValue    'restore new value
        If NewValue < OldValue Then
            Delta = OldValue - NewValue
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Offset(0, 1).Value + Delta
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If a value in column **A** is reduced by user action, the value in column **B** *(in the adjacent cell)* will be increased by the same amount.

If the value in column **A** is increased, then no action is taken.  If more than one cell in column **A** is changed at the same time, no action is taken.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of dislike that you have not showed any effort to solve your question, but given it is a fairly intriguing topic I gave it a go as a form of a nice "practice homework" for myself.

This code produces the expected result:

```
Dim oldval As Long
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
   If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count)) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value2) Then
            oldval = Target.Value2
        Else
            oldval = 0
        End If
   End If

End Sub
```

This first procedure is used to store the original value before change ^

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count)) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = oldval - Target.Value2
    End If
End Sub
```

And upon change, displays the difference in column B ^

> Input Data:

[image]

> Upon change in Column A *(result as expected)*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have this, that will add sum on column A and B on `workbook_open` and then use it if A or B changes the value.

This should go to the ThisWorkbook code area:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) + Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i)
Next i

End Sub
```

This should got to the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Cells(Target.Row, 2) = Cells(Target.Row, 3) - Cells(Target.Row, 1)
    End
End If
If Target.Column = 2 Then
    Cells(Target.Row, 1) = Cells(Target.Row, 3) - Cells(Target.Row, 2)
    End
End If
End Sub
```